# Delphi RTTI information and packages

Tags: delphi, rtti

I am trying to iterate through the RTTI information of Delphi code. When I load a package, I don't seem to be able to get the information via RTTI, even if the package is loaded before hand.

I am looking at the code from this [article](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/05/going-beyond-dependency-injection-with.html), which uses RTTI to mimic MEF, but have the same issue as well. Any ideas ?

**Update**

When I get the RttiContext and iterate through it, the classes that are in the packages are not shown. For example, using the code from [Embarcadero article on querying for type information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Querying_for_Type_Information), as shown below doesn't show the classes in the package - does this imply that although the package is loaded, the classes are not yet there?

```
for LType in FContext.GetTypes do
    begin
       WriteLn(LType.Name);
    end;
```

Comment: what is exactly the "same issue": what problem you have? is it an error code, no data returned, invalid data returned, or what?

Comment: See update - still trying to summarise the problem as a question!

Comment: Are you using `TRttiPackage` to get the package types?

Comment: Yes, although when I iterate through the package (using Context.GetPackages), I get the main exe only, so something is going wrong when I load the package. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!

I went back to my original code, and turned on RunTime Packages for the project. The important information from the Embarcadero docwiki is "*Note that the example must be built using run-time packages; otherwise, the types are built into the application directly*"